Chaining two WireGuard interfaces
I have an Ubuntu VPS running WireGuard server (set up with algo). I connect this server to another VPN (Hide.me).
I want clients of my VPN to have IP of Hide.me VPN, but clients of my VPN lose the internet connection after Hide.me is up.
My WireGuard interface is wg0
Hide.me interface is vpn
10.49.0.0/16 is my WireGuard subnet
55555 is Hide.me routing table
ip rule:
0:      from all lookup local
9:      from 10.49.0.0/16 lookup main
10:     from all lookup 55555
220:    from all lookup 220
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

ip route show table main:
default via 10.0.0.1 dev ens3
default via 10.0.0.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.227 metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.227 metric 100
10.0.0.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.227 metric 100
10.49.0.0/16 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.49.0.1
169.254.0.0/16 dev ens3 scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev ens3 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.227 metric 100
169.254.169.254 via 10.0.0.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.227 metric 100

ip route show table 55555:
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.141.246.1 dev vpn mtu 1392
default dev lo
10.141.246.1 dev vpn scope link mtu 1392
throw 45.144.196.118
throw <my ip>
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.141.246.1 dev vpn mtu 1392
throw 209.250.251.37
throw 217.182.206.81
throw 255.255.255.255

I've tried to connect to my VPN and ping 8.8.8.8. 100% packet loss. However, I see a bunch of these on the server via tcpdump -i wg0:
17:21:37.112380 IP 10.49.0.3 > dns.google: ICMP echo request, id 16, seq 1, length 64
And via tcpdump -v -i vpn | grep '10[.]49[.]' I see:
dns.google > 10.49.0.3: ICMP echo reply, id 16, seq 1, length 64
Which makes me think that packets are lost because they don't know how to get to 10.49.0.3 from the vpn interface. Am I right?
Let me know if there's any info I can provide to make it more clear.
